# GetTag of Fragment returns the null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragment, fragmentmanager

Using an application in which the multiple Fragments are in used and 
following code to fetch selected position of the fragment.

```
private BaseFragment getSelectedFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager)
    {
        int item = getModel().getSelectedItem();//0th position last
        String tag = String.valueOf(item);
        BaseFragment fragment = (BaseFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag); //error shown at this line
        return fragment;
    }
```

and calling above method from

```
public boolean onBackPressed() 
{
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
   BaseController fragmentController =             getSelectedFragment(fragmentManager).getController();
}
```

and crashed due to following errors

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String **xxx.android.fwk.app.fragment.BaseFragment.getTag()' on a null object refrence.**

replacing a fragment by using following code

```
private void displaySelectedFragment()
    {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            // pop any inner fragments that have been added.
            fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }

        // get the selected item position
        int selectedItem = model.getSelectedDrawerItem().getItemId();

        String tag = String.valueOf(selectedItem);
        Bundle extras = model.getExtras();

        BaseFragment newFragment = NomadFragmentManager.getInstance().getFragment(selectedItem, extras);
        if (newFragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.replace(R.id.container, newFragment, tag);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
```

so what's the actual problem cause ? digging into this code.
Any help much appriciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: While replacing fragment you are giving a 'tag' to fragment or not?

Comment: @SurenderKumar : yea, proving the tag while replacing the fragment, updated answer with fragment replacing code.

Comment: Can you add code from where you calling this method. Because may be fragment manager is coming null.

Comment: Try to check the tag you are setting to fragment while replacing is same while finding fragment using Log. Try this.

Comment: @SurenderKumar :  Getting Fragment as null at this line BaseFragment fragment = (BaseFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [Document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String))

> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is
>   essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently
>   added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then
>   add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

Replacing a `Fragment` will completely remove it from back stack. So, in case you are trying to retrieve the `Tag` after transaction to other `Fragment` then it will not be available. You should add the `Fragment`s to back stack using
`addToBackStack(tagName)`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. depth of the problem you mentioned.

Comment: adding the addTobackstack(tag) before commit resolved the issue of the

Answer (score 0):

From your crash log,it seems this is not the line number where you are getting the crash. The crash is due to the call of getTag() from a null fragment. Maybe after this method returns null and then you are using that fragment instance which gives null pointer exception.

```
BaseFragment fragment = (BaseFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
 if(fragment != null){
     return fragment.
 }
 return null;
```

Maybe putting debug point at `fragment != null` might clarify your issue.

> UPDATE

After your code update,you should not get any null pointer further. but you should put a log to check wheather it becomes null or not.

Comment: bpr10 : I added a comment where the line number shows, and will try to putting a debug but what is the actual cause for this problem ?

Comment: I added a log below this line,   BaseFragment fragment = (BaseFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag); and last fragment.getTag shows 0th position and app crashed drammatically !!!!

Comment: Can you please update the complete code in your question.

Comment: From your logs it's clear that you are calling a method from  a null fragment.  In onbackpresssed() you have called  getSelectedFragment(fragmentManager).getController() 
without checking whether getSelectedFragment() gives null or  not. Try putting a null check in onBackPressed.

Comment: I am getting a fragment as null for above question, Checked @bpr10

Answer (score 0):

For above problem, as described above the Fragment is coming as null.

So,

```
BaseFragment frag = getSelectedFragment(fragmentManager);
if(frag  == null) return true;
BaseController fragmentController = frag.getController();
```

Resolved the issue by putting check of null reference.